# Is it possible to Cap a GridFS collection?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to store my application results in a mongo database.  There are some issues to this, first we generate a lot of data because it is raw image files, up to 50MB per record and 5 records per second at full speed, that's worst case though not typical. This isn't a problem using gridFS. In the mongod.cfg we are using directoryPerDB: true and I create a symlink for the Results database folder to a dedicated SSD where all the results database is kept.  All the settings data is kept in a couple different databases on the OS drive, and the results data has a dedicated drive. This is all working great for our application.

My problem is filling up the results disk. I need to basically have a capped collection to a max size, and then delete only the oldest files.  But I don't see a way to do this with gridFS? Is there a setting  or something I'm missing that would allow capping this?

I found this answer [GridFS disk management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755460/gridfs-disk-management) but that seems to apply to mongod, and i don't think you can set a quota per database as the Results database is the only one I need to be limited.

At this point I guess i will write a task that cleans the oldest files out periodically if the total is over a threshold limit, i'm just afraid this is not going to be very efficient.  Are there any recommendations on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a long story short: you can not cap GridFS in a useful way. Here is why:

When you store a file in GridFS, it is split into chunks of 255kB, by default in a collection named `fs.chunks`, which absolutely can be capped by doing

```
db.createCollection("fs.chunks",{capped:true, size:52428800})
```

The capping would apply to those chunks, which are individual documents. So when you add a file which would make the `fs.chunks` to exceed its cap, only chunks of the oldest files would be removed. Another problem would be that the files metadata, which is stored in `fs.files` by default, would not be updated, leaving stale entries in `fs.files` for which no entries in `fs.chunks` are present any more, or – worse – only a fraction of the chunks are still present.

There are ways to overcome this (checking if the size in bytes of the chunks combined equals the length field of the `fs.files` document of the respective file, for example), but they are at least as complicated (and much slower!) as doing a check pre-insert wether the collection would exceed the threshold using the collections stats and delete as many of the oldest files as needed to fit the new file in without exceeding the threshold.

The latter, by the way, is my suggestion on how to solve your problem.

Another solution would be to use a dedicated instance with the limitations applied in my answer to the question you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, you made it very clear.  I think the best option for me will be the last you suggested, to make a dedicated instance. As a follow up question, using this method with --quota and --quotafiles, is the behavior that it will replace the oldest records with the new inserts?

Comment: Nope, it will just limit the size available to the instance. You would have to implement a purging logic anyway. Hence I suggested implementing it anyway.

Comment: So I thought I had this working.  I went with a new instance database and set a quota.  How is the quota distributed between the GridFS and the other files? It seems I'm getting "quota exceeded" when trying to insert the gridfs chunks even though I'm at less than 60% of the overall limit.  I set my clean up threshold at 75% thinking I was being conservative, so my cleanup never runs before I exceed quota.  Is there a way to specify how much of the quota is allocated to gridFS and how much to other data?

Comment: @trashrobber Sadly, there is no way to achieve what you want this way. I assume we are talking of filesystem quota here? The problem is that MongoDB preallocates a new datafile when the first entry is written into the last datafile. So your filesystem quota might well exceed before the data has the size allocated via the filesystem. You should check the actual size of you GridFS collection has programmatically and trigger a purge if a new entry exceeds a configured size.